# Como fazer para juntar dois valores de um array em somente um?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Por exemplo:
Se eu tenho um array que armazena as horas e outro array que vai armazenar os minutos

```
const arrayHora = [10]
const arrayMinuto = [53]
```

Como faria para juntar os dois valores dos arrays para juntos ficarem = [1053] ou = [10:53]

Comment: Esse arrayHora/arrayMinuto sempre vão ter uma única posição?

Comment: Eles vão ter somente somente uma posição. Visto que é somente 1 input (na verdade 1 de HORA e 1 de MINUTO)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Se cada array vai conter apenas uma posição, não faz sentido utilizar arrays. Seja como for, se precisar mesmo de utilizar arrays, pode também fazê-lo da seguinte forma: [...arrayHora, ...arrayMinuto].join(':')

Comment: `[\`${arrayHora[0]}:${arrayMinuto[0]}\`]`

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você pretende acessar a variável de cada array e "montar" um horário.

```js
const arrayHora = [10]
const arrayMinuto = [53]

var horario = arrayHora[0] + ":" + arrayMinuto[0]

console.log(horario)
```

Lembrando:

- O horario se torna uma variável string nesse caso.
- Usa-se o "[0]" onde 0 é o index do array, logo se o array for maior, você pode iterar/acessar diretamente pelo número do index do array.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um forEach e usar template literals. A ideia é que você chame a função a seguir, passando dois arrays com tamanhos iguais, onde o primeiro contém as horas e o segundo contém os minutos. Ele checa se o tamanho dos arrays são condizentes e não nulos e por fim, retorna um array de strings, onde cada string contém "hora:minutos" inseridos nos parâmetros.

```
function parseHour(hoursArray = [], minutesArray = []) {
  const parsedData = [];

  if (hoursArray.length !== minutesArray.length || minutesArray.length === 0)
    return "Arrays de tamanhos incompativeis";

  hoursArray.forEach((hour, index) => {
    parsedData.push(`${hour}:${minutesArray[index]}`);
  });

  return parsedData;
}
console.log(parseHour([21], [12])[0]);
```